# Combining a file dialog with buttons in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm struggling with making the transition from Tkinter to the more object-oriented approach of PyQt. My particular question focuses on combining file dialogs with buttons. In the example below, having lines of code I admittedly don't completely understand, I use a file dialog to load a time series, stored as a .csv file, into a dataframe and then plot it:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QFileDialog,

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Series Plotter'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.openFileNameDialog()
        self.show()

    def openFileNameDialog(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Choose File", "","csv (*.csv)", 
        options=options)
        df=pd.read_csv(fileName)
        df.plot()
        plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This works insofar as it automatically launches a file dialog and plots the chosen time series. However, I'd prefer to do the following:

1. Have an "open file" button in my window to launch the file dialog.
2. Have a "plot series" button in my window to plot the selected series. I imagine this button would need to be disabled until the series is actually chosen.

Despite looking at various tutorials, I'm struggling to find the pythonic way of doing this, a fact I attribute to my limited knowledge of the objected-oriented approach.

Comment: You can create a `mainwindow` and add the button over there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create a `main window` and add `button` there, and `connect` button click event to a function where you initialize the class you have created, something like this:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.resize(300,300)
        frame =QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.setCentralWidget(frame)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        frame.setLayout(layout)
        self.fileOpenButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Click to open File Dialog',self)
        layout.addWidget(self.fileOpenButton)
        self.fileOpenButton.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        wig = App()

def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output:

[image]

After clicking the button:

[image]

After selecting a file:

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly, and, more importantly, helps bridge the gap in my understanding of basic principals. Thanks.

Comment: @ThePyGuy for the sake of this example, specifically suggesting a main window is ininfluential, since you're not using any of its specific feature, as a standard QWidget would achieve exactly the same results.

Comment: yeah, the exact same thing can be achieved using QWidget as well